# Can't connect to postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

For the connection URL

```
postgres://swnstvngfhgcks:s6oqSe93DVkrcEnyJEHStzpfAt@ec2-54-235-170-124.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3tqm9uep7oufb
```

I use the following `persistence` settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HotelPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="postgres://ec2-54-235-170-124.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3tqm9uep7oufb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="swnstvngfhgcks"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="s6oqSe93DVkrcEnyJEHStzpfAt"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source"
                      value="sql/hotel_postgres.sql"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [postgres://ec2-54-235-170-124.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3tqm9uep7oufb]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
```

Where am I wrong

Comment: add `jdbc:` at the beginning of your connection?

Comment: Also, you should probably remove the user / password from this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the javax.persistence.jdbc.url property to have a `jdbc:postgresql:` prefix instead of just `postgres:`

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-235-170-124.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3tqm9uep7oufb
```

Docs at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html